# SOLR Proximity Search setting

Tags: solr

I have some address data that I need to search. I am struggling a bit with the proximity search.

An eg. of address that I am trying to search is:

CATO STREET WEST LAUNCESTON TAS

and my search query for proximity search doesn't return anything when I try to search for (CATO WEST)~2

The configuration for the data field (schema.xml) is as follows:

```
<field name="street_name_space" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Request handler is as follows:

```
<requestHandler name="/proximity" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="defType">edismax</str>
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
        <str name="qf">street_name_space</str>
        <str name="qs">10</str>
        <str name="pf">street_name_space</str>
        <str name="ps">10</str>
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <str name="fl">street_name, street_name_clean, street_name_space</str>          
     </lst>
    </requestHandler>
```

Any idea what I shall be doing to get the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the KeywordTokenizerFactory you are using keeps the whole thing as a single term, so the only term indexed is 'cato street west launceston tas'. Of course this does not match your query.

Use some other tokenizer, like the [WhitespaceTokenizerFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html) and it should work

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using the ClassicTokenizerFactory